# The inequality $\dfrac{x^2-2x-24}{2k-2}<x+6(2k+2)$ where $k\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am supposed to solve the inequality $$\dfrac{x^2-2x-24}{2k-2}<x+6(2k+2)$$ where $k$ is a real parameter $(k\in\mathbb{R})$.

Firstly, I would to ask you if solving an inequality with a parameter means to find the values of the parameter for which the inequality holds.

The given inequality is equivalent to $$\dfrac{x^2-2kx-24k^2}{2k-2}<0$$ I did this because when we are solving inequalities the right-hand side must be zero. Shall we do that when solving inequalities with parameters? What to do next? I tried to find the discriminant of the numerator $D=k^2+24k^2=25k^2\ge0$

Comment: Hint: There are two cases: $2k-2<0$ and $2k-2>0$. (If $2k-2=0$ the inequality is ill-defined, so you can ignore that case.)

Comment: @TonyK, Thank you for the response. I don't get that. How are these cases helping and what was the intuition that led to them? For example, in the first case we want $2k-2<0\iff k<1$ and $x^2-2kx-24k^2>0$ for the inequality to hold. The discriminant is $25k^2$ and $\sqrt{D}=\sqrt{25k^2}=5|k|$. This doesn't help much.

Comment: Because you can multiply out your second inequality by $2k-2$, but when you multiply an inequality by a negative number, you have to change $<$ to $>$.

Comment: Did you simplify correctly? It appears to me that you didnt. But out side of that, the answer to your general question is yes. You find all values $k$ such that the inequality holds.

Comment: @NewbieMather, I think I did.

Comment: @TonyK, I got your point to some extent. Now in the first case we will arrive at $2(k-1)(x^2-2kx-24k^2)>0$. What now? We still can't factor the third term as we don't know if $k$ is negative or positive.

Comment: Double check it.

Comment: @NewbieMather, I did.

Comment: I give up.${}{}$

Comment: There is no need to consider separate cases dependent on k's sign. Notice that you can multiply by the square of the denominator.

Comment: @Arthur: That is exactly what the OP did, in their comment. (It doesn't seem to have helped them though.)

Comment: "Firstly, I would to ask you if solving an inequality with a parameter means to find the values of the parameter for which the inequality holds" I think that it just means to solve for $x$ treating $k$ as a real number which does not depend on $x$ as some users here commented. Note that Darshan Patil's answer tries to find $k$ such that the inequality always holds.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) = \frac {x^2-2x-24}{2(k-1)}-x -12(k+1) < 0$$

This is a quadratic one so the graph will be parabolic or some shifted parabola

- take $\frac d{dx}$ We want the slope of tangent $=0$

$$\frac {2x-2}{2(k-1)} - 1=0 \implies \color{blue}{x = k}$$

This means the slope of the tangent is equal to zero only at $x = k$

- $\frac {d^2}{dx^2}$ we want this function to be decreasing now
- Why: The rate of the slope of tangent on either side of $x=k$ should be decreasing

$$\left[\frac 1{k-1}\right]_{x = k} < 0 \implies \color{blue}{k < 1}$$

Now, that we know that the highest point of a parabola is the point at which the slope of the tangent is  zero so if we make sure that $f(x = k) = 0$ then rest $\forall x$, $ f(x)<[f(x=k)=0]$
Thus, Solution of $\color{red}{f(x = k) = 0}$ & *$\color{red}{k <1 }$* will be critical one(say)$(k_c)$ and all answers $k<k_c$

Comment: You are assuming that the question asks to find $k$ such that the inequality always holds. I don't know if your assumption is correct. Assuming that your assumption is correct, I think that your answer has some errors. (1) $f''(x)$ should be $\dfrac{1}{k-1}$. (2) Our answer should be $k$ satisfying $f(k)\color{red}{\lt} 0$ and $\dfrac{1}{k-1}\lt 0$.